# Disable tooltip for element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to disable tooltips exclusively for videos on a Tumblr blog (https://testblognew.tumblr.com/), that is, I'd like no tooltip to appear when hovering over videos on the blog, but for a tooltip to remain over titled links.

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script><script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[title]").style_my_tooltips({
tip_follows_cursor:true,
tip_delay_time:75,
tip_fade_speed:50,
attribute:"title"
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

```css
#s-m-t-tooltip { 
    
}

.ui-tooltip {  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    padding-top:15px;
    
}


.ui-tooltip-content {
    background:{color:background};
    width:300px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
```

Full blog code:

```html
<!--
 
 
                theme: midnight v2
                - sorrism -
 
 
-->

<head>



<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
{block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
<!--Default Variables-->

<meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:Text" content="#cccccc"/>
<meta name="color:Link" content="#a7a7a7"/>
<meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Title" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Scrollbar" content="#d5d5d5"/>
<meta name="color:Accents" content="#f8f8f8"/>
<meta name="color:Text Borders" content="#eeeeee"/>

<meta name="if:Full Photoset" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Show Tags" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Infinite Scroll" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Manual Load" content="0"/>

<meta name="select:Captions" content="def" title="Default"/>
<meta name="select:Captions" content="inl" title="Inline"/>
<meta name="select:Captions" content="hide" title="Hide"/>

<meta name="image:Icon" content=""/>

<meta name="select:Post Width" content="250" title="250px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="275" title="275px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="300" title="300px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="325" title="325px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="350" title="350px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="375" title="375px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="400" title="400px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="450" title="450px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="500" title="500px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="540" title="540px"/>
<meta name="select:Post Width" content="600" title="600px"/>

<meta name="text:Post Spacing" content="100"/>

<meta name="select:Font" content="arial" title="Arial"/>
<meta name="select:Font" content="trebuchet ms" title="Trebuchet ms"/>
<meta name="select:Font" content="inconsolata" title="Inconsolata"/>
<meta name="select:Font" content="Helvetica" title="Helvetica"/>
<meta name="select:Font" content="Roboto" title="Roboto"/>

<meta name="select:Font Size" content="10px" title="10px"/>
<meta name="select:Font Size" content="11px" title="11px"/>
<meta name="select:Font Size" content="12px" title="12px"/>
<meta name="select:Font Size" content="13px" title="13px"/>
<meta name="select:Font Size" content="14px" title="14px"/>

<meta name="text:Link 1 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 1" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 2 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 2" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 3 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 3" content=""/>

<meta name="text:Profile Title" content="profile"/>
<meta name="text:Ask Title" content="contact"/>
<meta name="text:Archive Title" content="archive"/>

<!--CSS customization here. -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://static.tumblr.com/sas2ex2/HFinqriui/photoset.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//use.edgefonts.net/{select:font}:n4,i4,n5,n6,n7.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

/*tumblr controls and lightbox*/

.tmblr-iframe-overlay {margin: 0;}

.tmblr-lightbox {background:rgba({RGBcolor:background}, .95)!important;}

.tmblr-lightbox img {opacity:0;}

.lightbox-caption {
    color:{color:title}!important;
    font-family:inherit!important;
    font-size:1em!important;
    font-weight:normal!important;
    text-shadow:none!important;
}

.lightbox-image {

    
    -moz-box-shadow:none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none!important;
    box-shadow:none!important;
    -moz-border-radius:0px!important;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px!important;
    border-radius:0px!important;
    padding:0px!important;
    margin:0px!important;
    border:0!important;
    opacity:1!important;
    
   
}



.lightbox-target {
    left: 0px;
}

.lightbox .lb-image:

.vignette {opacity:0!Important;}


}

/*tooltip*/

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script><script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[title]").style_my_tooltips({
tip_follows_cursor:true,
tip_delay_time:75,
tip_fade_speed:50,
attribute:"title"
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

#s-m-t-tooltip { 
    
}

.ui-tooltip {  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    padding-top:15px;
    
}


.ui-tooltip-content {
    background:{color:background};
    width:300px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding:2px 5px;
}

/*scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:2px;
    width:3px;
    background:inherit;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:{color:scrollbar};
    border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
}

/*basics*/

.tmblr-full:last-child {
    padding-bottom:20px!Important;
}

*, body {myedit:crosshair;}

body {
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast!important;
    background:{color:background};
    color:{color:text};
    font:normal {select:font size}/1.4em {select:font}, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em!important;
    word-wrap:break-word;    
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    margin:0;

    
}

a {
    color:{color:text};
    text-decoration:none; 
    transition:all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .2s ease;
    -o-transition:all .2s ease;      
}

a, a img {myedit: no;}

.text a, .caption a, .source a, .a a {color:{color:link};} /*decoration links*/

a:hover:not(.when) {
    color:{color:link hover};
    text-decoration:none; 
}

img {
    opacity:1;
    border:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}

blockquote {
    padding:.25em 0 .25em 15px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:.5em 0;
    border-left:0px solid {color:text borders};
}

pre {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:inherit!important;
    background:transparent;
    font-family:inherit!Important;
    font-size:inherit!important;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    white-space:-moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space:-pre-wrap;
    white-space:-o-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

p {margin:1em 0;}

p:first-of-type {margin-top:0;}

p:last-of-type {margin-bottom:0;}

b, strong, b a, strong a {color:{color:title};}

ol, ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:0;
}

li {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:30px;
}

ol li {counter-increment:list;}

ol li:before {
    content:counter(list, decimal-leading-zero);
    left:0;    
    position:absolute;    
}

ul li:before {
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    vertical-align:baseline!important;
    content:'›';
}

.chat li:before, .pagenotes li:before {display:none;}

small, big, sub, pre {
    font-size:1em!important;
    line-height:1.5em!important;
    vertical-align:baseline!important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-size:1em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:{color:title};
    font-weight:normal;
    }

hr {
    border:none;
    box-shadow:0;
    margin:1.5em 25%;
    border-top:1px solid {color:text borders};
}

/*header*/

header {
    width:{select:post width}px;
    margin:140px auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: inconsolata;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: none-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;    
}

.ico {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:35px;
}

.ico img { /*icon*/
    margin:0 auto;    
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
}

.about {
    position:relative;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

.desc {
    padding:25px 0;
    opacity:0;
}

.dnav {margin-top:1.0em;
       margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.dnav a {
    font-size: 11px; 
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.dnav a:hover::after {color:{color:link}!important;}

.dnav a:last-of-type::after {display:none;}


nav {
    font-size: 11px; 
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
}

nav a {margin:0 0px;}

#blogt {
    
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight:bold;
        /*color:{color:title};*/ 
    
}

/*pagination*/

footer {
{block:ifinfinitescroll}
{block:ifnotmanualload}
    display:none;
{/block:ifnotmanualload}    
{/block:ifinfinitescroll} 
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto 150px auto;
    width:{select:post width}px;
    -webkit-animation-name: none-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; 
}

#pagination {
{block:ifinfinitescroll}
    display:none;
{/block:ifinfinitescroll}    
}

footer a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
    font-size:.8em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}

.nice {  
    position:fixed;
    right:15px;
    font-size:.9em;
    bottom:10px;
}

.nice a {color:{color:text};}

#infscr-loading {display:none!important;}

/*posts*/

section {
    width:{select:post width}px;
    margin:{text:post spacing}px auto 150px auto;
    {block:ifinfinitescroll}{block:indexpage}
    margin-bottom:0;
    {/block:indexpage}{/block:ifinfinitescroll}    
}

.posts {
    width:{select:post width}px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:105px; {post spacing}
    -webkit-animation-name: none-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.likereblog { 
   transition: .2s ease-in-out; 
   -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out; 
   -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
   opacity:0;
   position:absolute; 
   width: 30px; 
   height:60px; 
   margin-left:605px;
   margin-top:0px; 
  } 

.post, .photo, .pxu-photo {margin-bottom: 0.7em;}

.post:hover .likereblog {
opacity:1;
}

.posts img {
    height:auto;
    width: auto;  
    margin: auto;
    backface-visibility:visible; 
    min-width: 100%;
     
}

.photo img {display:block;
    
} 

.photo a {display:none;}

.photo a:first-child {display:inline!important;} /*edit*/

.go .set {display:none;}

.stop {display:none;}

.go .stop {display:block!important;}
 
.media {
    display:block;  
    position:relative;   
}
 
.media iframe, .tumblr_video_container {display:block;}
 
.tumblr_video_container {
    width:auto!important;
    height:auto!important;
}

a.read_more, a.tumblr_blog,.readmore {text-transform:lowercase;}

.posts img, .posts li, .posts blockquote {max-width:100%;}

.caption img, .caption iframe {max-width:100%;}

/*text*/

.title {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:3px;
  /*  color:{color:title}; EDIT */
}

.title a {
    color:{color:title};
    border-bottom:1px solid {color:text borders};
}

.title a:hover {color:{color:link hover};}

.ted {margin-top:20px;}

/*quote*/

.quote {
    margin-top: 7em;
    font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;
    font-size: 1.6em!important;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform: initial;
    letter-spacing: initial;
        
}
   
.source {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    

}

/*captions*/

.caption {position:relative;}


.caption blockquote {padding-left:10px;}    

.inl .caption *:not(a):not(ul):not(ol):not(li) {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
    display:inline;
}

.inl .caption:not(ul):not(ol):not(li) {text-align:center;}

.inl .caption p:first-of-type {display:block!important;}

.inl .caption p:first-of-type::after {content:' ';}

.inl .caption blockquote {
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    border:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.inl .caption blockquote p{display:block!important;}

.inl .caption p {
    display:block!important;
    margin:.5em 0!important;
}

.inl .caption p:first-of-type {
    display:inline!important;
    margin:0!important;
}

.inl .caption *::after:not(a):not(ul):not(ol):not(li) {content:' ';}

.posts img, .posts li, .posts blockquote, .caption img {max-width:100%;}

.caption *:last-child, .a *:last-child, .tex *:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0!Important;
    padding-bottom:0!Important;
    
} 

{block:indexpage}.hide .caption {display:none!important;}{/block:indexpage} 

/*audio*/
 
 .tumblr_audio_player {
width:100%;
clear:both;
width:calc({select:Post Width} - 20px);}
 
.soundcloud_audio_player
{width: 100%;}

/*asks*/

.q {
    text-align:center;
    font-style:italic;
}

.as span {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:15px auto 0 auto;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:{color:Accents};
}

.as a {color:{color:text};}

.as a:hover {color:{color:link hover};}

.a {
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
}

.a:not(ul):not(ol):not(li) {text-align:center;}

/*chat*/

.chat {
    margin:0;    
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.l {
    padding:10px;
}

.l.odd {background:{color:accents};}

.label {
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;    
    font-weight:bold;
    color:{color:title};
    display:inline-block;
}

/*permalink and notes*/

.when {
    font-family: arial; /*edit*/
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-size:.6em;
}

.when a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:{color:text};
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
}

.when a:hover {color:{color:link hover};}

.tags {
        display:inline;
{block:indexpage}{block:ifnotshowtags}
    display:none;
{/block:ifnotshowtags}{/block:indexpage}  
{block:permalinkpage}
    display:block;
{/block:permalinkpage}    
}

.tags a {
    display:inline;
    opacity:.7;
    word-break:break-word;
}

.tags a:hover {opacity:1;}

.pagenotes {
    position:relative;
    height:0px;
    overflow:visible; 
}

.op.pagenotes {overflow-y:auto!important;}

.same {opacity:1;}

.pagenotes *:not(blockquote) {text-align:center!important;}

.ti {
    margin:30px 0;
    myedit: no;
}
 
.pagenotes a {text-decoration:none;}


ol.notes .action {
    color:{color:text borders};
    text-transform:uppercase;     
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:2px;    
    list-style-type:none; 
    padding:0;    
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

ol.notes li.note {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted {color:text borders};    
    padding:2px 0;
}

ol.notes /*li.note:nth-child(odd)*/ /*myedit*/ * {color:rgba({RGBcolor:title},.9);}

ol.notes li.note img.avatar {display:none!important;}

.more_notes_link, .notes_loading {
    display:block;
    color:{color:title};
    text-align:left;
}

{CustomCSS}

</style>

<!-- jquery -->

<!--
        NPF images fix v3.0 by @glenthemes [2021]
         git.io/JRBt7
--->
<script src="//npf-images-v3.github.io/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//npf-images-v3.github.io/recon.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src ="//static.tumblr.com/fwgzvyf/l6jnyutne/shythemes.vr.js"></script><script src="https://static.tumblr.com/qudkd6d/Az6nkemqr/pxuphotoset.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
        track:true
    });
    $('.go .photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset({
        lightbox: true,
        rounded: false,
        gutter: '0px', /*edit*/
        photoset: '.photo-slideshow',
        photoWrap: '.photo-data',
        photo: '.pxu-photo'      
    }); 
    $('.pro').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('op')) {
        $('.desc').noneTo("200", 0);        
        $('.about').animate({height:0}, 600);
    } 
    else {
        $('.about').stop().animate({height:$('.desc').outerHeight()}, 600);
        $('.desc').delay(300).noneTo("200", 1);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('op');return false;
    });
    $('.ti').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('op')) {
        $('.same').noneTo("200", 0);        
        $('.pagenotes').animate({height:0}, 600);
    } 
    else {
        $('.pagenotes').stop().animate({height:'350px'}, 600);
        $('.same').delay(300).noneTo("200", 1);
    }
    $('.pagenotes').toggleClass('op');return false;
    });    
});



</script>

</head>

<body>

<header>
{block:ifIconImage}<a href="/" class="ico"><img src="{image:Icon}"></a>{/block:ifIconImage}
    <nav>{block:ifAskTitle}<a href="/ask">{text:ask title}</a>{/block:ifAskTitle}{block:ifProfileTitle}<a class="pro">{text:profile title}</a>{/block:ifProfileTitle}<a id="blogt" href="/">{Title}</a>{block:ifArchiveTitle}<a href="/archive">{text:archive title}</a>{/block:ifArchiveTitle}</nav>
    <div class="about"><div class="desc">{Description}</div></div>
    
    <div class="dnav">{block:ifLink1}<a href="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</a>{/block:ifLink1}{block:ifLink2}<a href="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</a>{/block:ifLink2}{block:ifLink3}<a href="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</a>{/block:ifLink3}</div>
    </div></div>
</header>

<section id="entries" class="{block:indexpage}{block:iffullphotoset}go{/block:iffullphotoset}{/block:indexpage}{block:permalinkpage}go{/block:permalinkpage}">{block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="1280" inlineNestedMediaWidth="1280"}<article class="posts {select:captions}"><div class="post"> 
  <div class="likereblog"> 
     {likebutton color="red" size="20"} {reblogbutton color="red" size="20"} 
  </div> 

{block:Quote}<div class="title quote">{Quote}</div>
{block:Source}<div class="source">{Source}</div>{/block:Source}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="tex {block:title}ted{/block:title}">{Body}</div>
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<div class="title"><a href="{URL}">{Name}</a></div>
{block:Description}<div class="tex ted">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}

{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<ol class="chat {block:title}ted{/block:title}">
{block:Lines}
<li class="l {Alt}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}</li>
{/block:Lines}
</ol>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Photo}
<div class="photo"><a href="#" onclick="Tumblr.Lightbox.init([{ width: {PhotoWidth-HighRes}, height: {PhotoHeight-HighRes}, low_res: '{PhotoURL-HighRes}', high_res: '{PhotoURL-HighRes}' }]); $('body').toggleClass('tumblr_lightbox_active'); return false">
    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">
</a><!--{LinkURL}-->{block:indexpage}<a href="{permalink}">{/block:indexpage}{block:indexpage}</a>{/block:indexpage}{block:permalinkpage}{linkclosetag}{/block:permalinkpage}</div>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}<div class="hug">{block:indexpage}<div class="photo set">{block:photos}<a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"></a>{/block:photos}</div>{/block:indexpage}<div class="photo-slideshow stop" id="photoset_{PostID}" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">{block:Photos}<div class="photo-data"><div class="pxu-photo"><img alt="{PhotoAlt}" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" width="{PhotoWidth-highres}" height="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" data-highres="{PhotoURL-highres}" data-width="{PhotoWidth-highres}" data-height="{PhotoHeight-highres}"></div><a class="tumblr-box" rel="post-{PostID}" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"></a></div>{/block:Photos}</div></div></div>
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Video}<div class="video">{Video-500}</div>{/block:Video}

{block:Audio}
<div class="tumblr_audio_player">
{block:AudioEmbed}{AudioEmbed color="white"}{/block:AudioEmbed}</div>
{/block:Audio}

{block:Answer}
<div class="q">{Question}<div class="as"><span>sent by {Asker}</span></div></div><div class="a">{Answer}</div>
{/block:Answer}

{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
<!-- -->
<br>{block:Date}<div class="when"><a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank">{block:indexpage}{DayOfMonthWithZero}{MonthNumberWithZero}{/block:indexpage}{block:permalinkpage}{DayOfMonthWithZero}{MonthNumberWithZero}<p><span class="tags">{block:Tags}<a href="{TagUrl}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}</span><!--{timeago}-->{/block:permalinkpage}</a>{block:permalinkpage}{block:RebloggedFrom}<br><a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}">via</a>{block:ContentSource}/<a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}">source</a>{/block:ContentSource}{/block:RebloggedFrom}{/block:permalinkpage}</div>
{/block:Date}

{block:PostNotes}{block:notecount}<div class="title ti">{NoteCountWithLabel}</div>{/block:notecount}<div class="pagenotes"><div class="same">{PostNotes}</div></div>
{/block:PostNotes}    
    
</article>


{/block:Posts}</section>
{block:pagination}<footer><div id="pagination">
{block:previouspage}<a href="{previouspage}">&laquo; back</a>{block:nextpage}/{/block:nextpage}{/block:previouspage}{block:nextpage}<a href="{nextpage}">next &raquo;</a>{/block:nextpage}</div>{block:ifinfinitescroll}{block:ifmanualload}<a style="myedit: no;" class="load">load more</a>{/block:ifmanualload}{/block:ifinfinitescroll}</footer>{/block:pagination}
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}
{block:indexpage}
<script src="https://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/QBym35odk/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
{block:ifinfinitescroll}
<script src="https://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>{/block:ifinfinitescroll}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('section'); 
{block:ifinfinitescroll}    
    $container.infinitescroll({
        itemSelector: 'article',
        navSelector: '#pagination',
        nextSelector: '#pagination a',
        loadingImg: '',
        loadingText: '<em></em>',
        errorCallback: function(){ $('.load').text('no more posts').parent().delay(4000).slideUp(400); },            
        bufferPx: 3000
    },
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        $newElems.css({opacity: 0, zIndex: -1}); 
{block:iffullphotoset}
        $newElems.find('.photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset({
            lightbox: true,
            rounded: false,
            gutter: '0px', /*edit*/
            photoset: '.photo-slideshow',
            photoWrap: '.photo-data',
            photo: '.pxu-photo'                     
        }); 
{/block:iffullphotoset}            
        resizeVideos();
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
            $newElems.delay(600).animate({opacity: 1, zIndex: 1});  
        });           
    });
{block:ifmanualload}        
    $(window).unbind('.infscr');
    $('.load').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().noneTo("400", 0);
        $('section').delay(400).infinitescroll('retrieve').parent('body').find('.load').parent().delay(400).noneTo("400", 1); return false;  
    });
{/block:ifmanualload}  
{/block:ifinfinitescroll}  
});
</script>
{/block:indexpage}<a class="nice" href="https://sorrism.tumblr.com" target="_blank">σ</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // audio player
  var $audio = $('iframe.tumblr_audio_player');
  $audio.load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('head').append('<style type="text/css">' +
    '.audio-player { background: #000; color: #fff !important; }' +
    '.audio-player .audio-info .track-artist { color: #fff !important;              font-family:roboto!important; }' +
    '.audio-player .audio-info .track-name { color: #fff !important;                font-family:roboto!important; }' +
    '.audio-player .progress { background: rgb(255 255 255 / 20%);                                    !important ;}' +
      
    '</style>');
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tooltips are displayed because of Title attribute. You need to remove them in order to make them not appear. Here's a small piece of code which would remove the title attribute on hover in and put it back when you hover out

HTH

```
$("#youtube_iframe").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("tooltip-data", $(this).attr("title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
}, function(){
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("tooltip-data"));
    $(this).removeAttr("tooltip-data");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed "#youtube_iframe" to "iframe" alone so that the code would apply to Vimeo videos as well. I hope this alteration won't cause issues.